# Empty property value after Automapper v5 upgrade

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-5

I have the below code that has been working in v3 of Automapper but no longer in v5.  **UPDATE** It also works in v4.

`CallScheduleProfile` in its constructor sets a `Title` property to an instance of a class that passes a value of `true` to it.

`CallScheduleProfileViewModel` in its constructor sets a `Title` property to an instance of a different class that passes a value of `true` and `"Title"`.

I have setup the mappings in AutoMapper for all 4 classes and then I call Map.

The result is that the after the map the `Title` property on `CallScheduleProfileViewModel` has a boolean of `true` but `FriendlyName` is empty even though it's set in its constructor.

What I believe is happening is that the constructor on `CallScheduleProfileViewModel` is being called and `FriendlyName` is getting assigned but then when the mapping occurs it calls the constructor on `Entry` and then maps any properties on `UxEntry` that exist and assigns that to the `Title` property and by default `FriendlyName` will be null and because the `FriendlyName` doesn't exist on `UxEntry` its value isn't copied across.

I may be wrong in that assumption but either way how do I get `FriendlyName` populated on the mapping?

**Update** : I looked at Automapper [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings) on nested types and the issue exists with code supplied in the docs too. If I add a string property to `InnerDest` and set its value in `OuterDest` constructor, after the `Map` its value is null.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<UxEntry<bool>, Entry<bool>>();

        cfg.CreateMap<CallScheduleProfile, CallScheduleProfileViewModel>();
    });

    var old = new CallScheduleProfile();

    var newmodel = Mapper.Map<CallScheduleProfile, CallScheduleProfileViewModel>(old);

    Console.WriteLine(newmodel.Title.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(newmodel.Title.FriendlyName);
}

public class UxEntry<T>
{
    public static implicit operator T(UxEntry<T> o)
    {
        return o.Value;
    }

    public UxEntry()
    {
        this.Value = default(T);
    }

    public UxEntry(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}


public class CallScheduleProfile
{
    public CallScheduleProfile()
    {
        this.Title = new UxEntry<bool>(true);
    }

    public UxEntry<bool> Title { get; set; }

}

public class Entry<T>
{
    public Entry()
    {
    }

    public Entry(T value, string friendlyName)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.FriendlyName = friendlyName;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(Entry<T> o)
    {
        return o.Value;
    }
}


public class CallScheduleProfileViewModel 
{
    public CallScheduleProfileViewModel()

    {
        this.Title = new Entry<bool>(true, "Title");
    }
    public Entry<bool> Title { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `Automapper` maps this property to `null` because :

A) Constructor for type `Entry<T>` set this property to `null` value

B) Automapper creates a new instance of `Entry<T>` after (!) the constructor in `CallScheduleProfileViewModel` is invoked.

C) There are no other rules set for Automapper

What you can do here is to change configuration, so that you let Automapper know that there should be a default value used for one of the properties :

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            // when UxEntry is mapped to Entry value "Title" is used for property FriendlyName
            cfg.CreateMap<UxEntry<bool>, Entry<bool>>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FriendlyName, opt => opt.UseValue("Title"));

            cfg.CreateMap<CallScheduleProfile, CallScheduleProfileViewModel>();
        });
```

Now we can remove redundant property initialization from constructor in `CallScheduleProfileViewModel`.

Running your code without other changes produces following output :

```
true    
Title
```

Comment: I actually found `cfg.CreateMap<CallScheduleProfile, CallScheduleProfileViewModel>().ForMember(dest =>dest.Title, o => o.UseDestinationValue());` also worked